# Computation of the integral of the product of a double exponential and an exponential

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to compute the following integral:

$$\int_0^t\exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda s}-\lambda s\right)ds\space\space\space(1)$$

An integral near from this one is:

$$\int_0^t\exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda s}\right)ds\space\space\space   (2)$$

and may be computed by setting the following change of variables $u=e^{-2\lambda s}$. This leads to a integral of the following kind:
$$\int_c^d \frac{e^{au}}{u}du$$
By using the integral serie development of the exponential, a calculation of the integral (2) may be achieved. The remaining issue is the speed of convergence of the calculus but that is another issue that is a numeric one.
Unfortunately, if i am not wrong, this trick is not  usable to compute the integral (1). Any idea to obtain an usable calculus of the integral (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$I=\int\exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda s}-\lambda s\right)\,ds$$ let (not so obvious, I agree but quite close to your $u$)
$$s=-\frac 1{\lambda }{\log \left(\frac{ x}{\sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^2}{2\lambda
   }}}\right)}\implies ds=-\frac{dx}{\lambda  x}$$
$$I=-{\lambda  \sqrt{\frac{2\alpha ^2}{\lambda }}}\int e^{x^2}\,dx=-{\lambda  \sqrt{\frac{2\alpha ^2\pi}{2\lambda }}}  \text{erfi}(x)$$

Back to $s$, this should give
$$I=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi\alpha ^2}{2\lambda }}}{\alpha ^2}\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^2}{2\lambda }} e^{-\lambda  s}\right)$$ and simplifying
$$J=\int_0^t\exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda s}-\lambda s\right)\,ds=\frac 1 \alpha \sqrt{\frac \pi {2\lambda}}\left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\alpha }{ \sqrt{2\lambda
   }}\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\alpha  }{
   \sqrt{2\lambda }}e^{-\lambda  t}\right) \right)$$

**Edit**

Making, as you thought about it, $u=e^{-2\lambda s}$ is good and leads for the antiderivative to $$I=\int -\frac{e^{\frac{\alpha ^2 u}{2 \lambda }}}{2 \lambda  \sqrt{u}}\,du$$ Now
$${\frac{\alpha ^2 u}{2 \lambda }}=x^2\implies u=\frac{2 \lambda  x^2}{\alpha ^2}\implies du=\frac{4 \lambda  x}{\alpha ^2}\,dx$$
$$I=-\frac{ \sqrt{\frac{2\lambda }{\alpha ^2}}}{\lambda }\int e^{x^2} \,dx=-\frac{ \sqrt{\frac{2\lambda }{\alpha ^2}}}{\lambda }\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(x)$$

Assuming $\alpha >0$ and $\lambda>0$, the definite integral is
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^t\exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda s}-\lambda s\right)\,ds=\frac 1 \alpha \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2\lambda}}\Big[ \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\alpha }{ \sqrt{2\lambda
   }}\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\alpha  }{
   \sqrt{2\lambda }}e^{-\lambda  t}\right)\Big]}$$

Comment: Exact. And of course, we may simplify $I$ like:$$\frac{1}{\alpha} \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2\lambda}} erfi(x)$$ thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @BenG73. In fact, almost up to the end, I did want to assume anything about the parameters.

Comment: For your knowledge, in my framework, my parameters $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ are positive coefficients of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. But, but, i spot an issue with your developement above: there is a minus in the erfi function that is missing. Indeed: $$erfi(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x exp(-t^2) dt$$ However not a big deal, we need to take the following variable change: $$x^2=-\frac{\alpha^2 u}{2 \lambda} $$

Comment: The preceding variable change $$x^2=-\frac{\alpha^2 u}{2 \lambda} $$ is not usable because this will lead to the square root of a negative number

Comment: Ok, i make a confusion. erfi is not the classic error function but the imaginary error function, right ?

Comment: @Ben. You got it !

Comment: For the implementation of the erfi function, i use the C++ Fadeeva package from the MIT: http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Faddeeva_Package is this the best one ?

Comment: is there a mistake in your result ? (before Edit) because i find $$\frac{1}{\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\lambda}} (erfi(1)-erfi(e^{-2\lambda t})$$  for me, the second variable change eliminates $\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\lambda}}$

Comment: @BenG73. I have no experience with this subroutine but according to my readings it seems to be very good. Is blue more convincing ? Back to serious, I tripled checked. Try with WA (just in case). Cheers :-)

Comment: Your calculus is right. mea culpa, i forgot to change the bounds after the second variable change... :(

Comment: @BenG73. Don(t worry ! If I was given a cent for each of these kinds of mistakes, I should be a millionaire.! Cheers :-)